# Is this a cabbage plant?

Tags: identification, cabbage

I have planted these plants which I was told is cabbage. It has been more than 120 days since I brought the seedlings, but it has not yet formed the head. So, I am, now, wondering if it is a cabbage?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it has the visual characteristics of a red type of cabbage. There are at least two reasons for not having a head appear: poor soil and genetics that confine its development to an ornamental type. If the soil is poor or too alkaline then it will produce a few small leaves and do nothing about a head. There are ornamental varieties which are designed not to produce a head, just a nice arrangement of leaves after which it breaks into flower stalks and is done.

Comment: But what's the average time (should I say any variety?) cabbage takes to matured and be harvested? Also, I hope even if it's an ornamental variety we could still eat the leaves, right?

Comment: 70 to 90 days for regular cabbage. Outer leaves on cabbage are usually tough and leathery, good for keeping bugs off but not great for eating.